# function is not defined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently moving my current project to a new one where react is used.
I do want to make a simple method/function but I do not get it to work.

The button is created somewhere else and I can't do it in the drawing.js class (screenshot). This because it needs to be in a div with the other buttons.

So I try to call the button and add an event but I get the message that the method is undefined.

How can I solve this? I basically want to make and call a method.

> 

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
 
class Drawing extends Component {
 constructor(props)
 {
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidMount()
 {
  var button = document.getElementById( 'draw' );
  button.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function ( event ) {handleClick();}, false );
  button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {handleClick();}, false );
 }

 handleClick() 
 {
  console.log("Clicked")
   }

 render()
 {
  return (
        <div ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}>
   </div>
     )
 }
}
 
export default Drawing;
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7JfJ.png)

Comment: Please include your code in your question as a [MCVE]

Comment: I added a screenshot of my code.

Comment: Screenshots are not well accepted in StackOverflow. Copy and paste the code into here, and please format the code too.

Comment: One suggestion, unrelated, but try making the code a but more readable.

Comment: Also, I am not a proffesional reactJS dev, but shouldn't `this.handleClick();` be used?

Comment: When I replace handleClick with this.handleClick I get following error: "this.handleClick is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember when creating functions using the function keyword and passing them as callback to events, those functions are executed in a different context where this context is not your component.
You can solve the problem by using bind or an arrow function, examples below.

One option

```
button.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function ( event ) {this.handleClick();}.bind(this), false );
button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {this.handleClick();}.bind(this), false );
```

Other

```
button.addEventListener( 'click', ( event ) => {this.handleClick();}, false );
```

Comment: Second example worked! Thank you. The first one did not work though